# Limits of two sequences.

Tags: limits

let $a_n$ and $b_n$ two sequences such that:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n-b_n|=1$

does that mean if $a_n$ has a finite limit then $b_n$? I know that the answer is NO, but I couldn't find an example for that.

Comment: $a_n=0$, $b_n=(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $a_n = 0$ and $b_n = (-1)^n$